# SwiftUI passing ViewModifier as parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a custom `TextField` view that consists of multiple adornment views. I want to be able to set up the inner `TextField` with view modifiers such as keyboard, capitalization, etc. that apply just to that sub-view.

Rather than creating properties for each of these I figured the best way would be to pass in a single optional `ViewModifier` parameter and use it something like this:

```
struct MySuperTextField: View {
    var vm: ViewModifier?

    var body: some View {
         TextField(...)
           .modifier( vm ?? EmptyModifier() )
         // ... more views here
    }
}
```

This doesn't work due to the `associatedType` in `ViewModifier`. Alas there is no such thing as *AnyViewModifier* either (and I could't figure out how to make one that worked).

Anyone manage to do something like this? I couldn't find anything searching the web.

An example would be

```
struct LastNameModifier: ViewModifier {
   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
       content
          .autocapitalization(.words)
          .textContentType(.familyName)
          .backgroundColor(.green)
          // ... anything else specific to names
   }
}

struct EmailModifier: ViewModifier {
   func body(content: Content) -> some View {
       content
          .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
          .textContentType(.emailAddress)
          .backgroundColor(.yellow)
          // ... anything else specific to emails
   }
}
```

and then use them with my `MySuperTextField` like this:

```
VStack {
    MySuperTextField("Last Name", $lastName, vm: LastNameModifier())

    MySuperTextField("Email", $email, vm: EmailModifier())
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what problem are you trying to solve. Can you add an example?

Comment: The issue is I have a common adorned TextField which is used to set things like names, email addresses, phone numbers, etc. each having its own keyboards and content type. So I want to set these per call. Right now I am able to do that by applying it to the whole view since there are no conflicts with the other views. However I can image something like a background color that I only want to apply to the "inner" TextField and not to the fully adorned view.

Comment: Seems more useful to have a general Form object that accepts a variadic input of setup structs. You can read more about multiple generic conformance here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID192

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can make your `MySuperTextField` accept a generic parameter:

```
struct MySuperTextField<V>: View where V: ViewModifier {
    private let placeholder: String
    @Binding private var text: String
    private let vm: V
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>, vm: V) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
        self.vm = vm
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .modifier(vm)
    }
}
```

Then, you can pass *some ViewModifier* as the parameter:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var text: String = "Test"

    var body: some View {
        MySuperTextField("Last Name", text: $text, vm: LastNameModifier())
    }
}
```

If you need a way to skip the `vm` parameter when creating `MySuperTextField`:

```
MySuperTextField("Last Name", text: $text)
```

you can create an extension:

```
extension MySuperTextField where V == EmptyModifier {
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        self._text = text
        self.vm = EmptyModifier()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since `ViewModifier` has an associated type that you cannot use as an instance variable but I propose you another way of use:

`MySuperTextField` does not have to maintain instances of the `ViewModifier` type.

```
struct MySuperTextField: View {
    @State var textValue = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $textValue)
    }
}
```

For each structure that conforms to the `ViewModifier` protocol you create an extension:

```
extension MySuperTextField {
    func lastNameModifier() -> some View {
        modifier(LastNameModifier())
    }

    func emailModifier() -> some View {
        modifier(EmailModifier())
    }
}
```

and you can use it this way:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MySuperTextField(textValue: "Last Name")
                .lastNameModifier()
            MySuperTextField(textValue: "Email")
                .emailModifier()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the ViewModifier up as a struct and just call it on the view. You just have to be specific as to the type, such as this buttonStyle modifier I used:

```
struct PurchaseButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    let geometry: GeometryProxy
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .frame(minWidth: 0, idealWidth: 300, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.all, geometry.size.height / 30)
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .background(.orange)
            .cornerRadius(30)

    }
}
```

The use is:

```
Button(...)
    .buttonStyle(PurchaseButtonStyle(geometry: Geometry))
```

You just have to write it to be the specific modifier. I just used this because it was handy in an app I was working on.

Comment: This doesn't solve/answer my question since I want to pass in styles and not hard-code them in the common view.

Comment: If you look, you will see I passed in a variable. You can pass in as many variables as you want to customize the style however you want. But, you have to return a specific type and ONLY a specific type. That was where you ran into problems. For mine, I was just trying to make a uniform button for the app, but I could have changed it however I wanted on the fly.