# How to apply view modifiers to a nested portion of a view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

i have this "TaskButton" which essentially is a button that when clicked, shows a loading spinner until the task is complete. In order to be used in a few places i've made this a re-usable view.

Each button will have a slightly different look & feel, so they can be styled with view modifiers, however, the modifiers modify the button, not the label, so the clickable area is not changed.

How can i apply modifiers to the nested label? Maybe by passing a generic viewmodifier as a parameter?

Code below:

```
import SwiftUI

// Run an async task and display a loader icon within button.
// Task must call an escaping callback to notify TaskButton that it has finished.
struct TaskButton: View {
    
    var text: String
    var task: ((@escaping () -> Void) -> Void)
    var loaderTint: Color = .white
    
    @State var isLoading = false
    
    func onClick() {
        isLoading = true
        task() {
            isLoading = false
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: onClick) {
            VStack {
                if (isLoading) { ProgressView().tint(loaderTint) }
                else { Text(text) }
            }
            // view modifier should go here.
            // otherwise the view-modified area is not clickable.
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TaskButton(text: "Click here!", task: { cb in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0, execute: {
            cb()
        })
    })
    .frame(height: 18)
    .modifier(bpLargeButtonStyleEnabled())
    .padding()
    .font(.sourceSans3Regular(size: 16))
}
```

Comment: You can pass view modifier as a parameter, Check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65752883/swiftui-passing-viewmodifier-as-parameter

Comment: By "view modifier", are you only referring to `bpLargeButtonStyleEnabled`? Or do you want to apply `frame`, `padding` etc to the button label too?

Comment: One modifier would be fine. I can always add the frame and padding to bpLargeButtonEnabled